# How to reset a contenteditable element in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am rendering an array of items, where each item has a `contenteditable` field.

**App.js**

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Item from "./Item";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([
    { id: 1, text: "It is raining all day long." },
    { id: 2, text: "The flower has a nice fragrance." },
    { id: 3, text: "The charging is complete." },
    { id: 4, text: "The room needs to be sweeped." }
  ]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {items.map((item) => (
        <Item key={item.id} item={item} />
      ))}

      <button>Reset</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Item.js**

```
const Item = ({ item }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p contentEditable="true">{item.text}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Item;
```

As you can see that in App.js I have a reset button. I want that when this reset button is clicked, the original content of all the Items must be displayed.

e.g. If one changes "It is raining all day long" to "It is not raining", when the reset button is pressed, it will change back to "It is raining all day long."

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank You very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround to this problem.

**App.js**

What we can do is, we can define a state in App.js, say `resets` which has an initial value of `0`. Thereafter, we pass this resets as a prop to the child component `<Item />`.

Now, when the reset button will be clicked, we increment the value of this `resets` by 1.

This is demonstrated in the following code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { item_data } from "./data";
import Item from "./Item";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(item_data);
  const [resets, setResets] = useState(0);
 
  const handleReset = () => {
    setResets((resets) => resets + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {items.map((item) => (
        <Item key={item.id} item={item} resets={resets} />
      ))}

      <button onClick={handleReset}>Reset</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Item.js**

Here, we define a conditional useEffect which runs every time the value of `resets` is changed. So, when this will occur, we grab our `contentEditable` field from the DOM, and set it's innerHTML to the original value, i.e., in this case `item.text`.

Here is the code demonstration:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Item = ({ item, resets }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const text = document.getElementById(`text-${item.id}`);
    text.innerHTML = item.text;
  }, [resets]);
 
  return (
    <div className="item">
      <p
        id={`text-${item.id}`}
        contentEditable={true}
        suppressContentEditableWarning={true}
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item.text }}
      ></p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Item;
```

Thank You for all your help. This solution is working for me in the time being. If there are any limitations to it, then please comment the same.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do so would be to save the initial state as the default state and when reset button is clicked, just change the current state to the default state which is initial state.

```
const initialState = [
    { id: 1, text: "It is raining all day long." },
    { id: 2, text: "The flower has a nice fragrance." },
    { id: 3, text: "The charging is complete." },
    { id: 4, text: "The room needs to be sweeped." }
  ]

 const [items, setItems] = useState(initialState);
```

For the reset button;

```
const onPress = () => {
   setItems(initialState);

}

  <button onClick={onPress}>Reset</button>
```

Comment: This won't work well, because the content-editable element doesn't store its state into the React state, so `items` will remain the same and React *probably* won't rerender the component.

Comment: Then how do you re-render the things when there are changes??

Comment: Yeah I have tried this. This doesn't work.

Comment: That's one of the hard points of React. It's so because `contenteditable` elements are [uncontrolled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html). You'd have to create a wrapper for it, that attaches an `oninput` event listener, update its state and send it out to its parent via a callback prop, that then updates its own state and rerenders its child with new props, that will rerender itself with the new value... Something like this. (You think it's messy because... it **is**.) Btw, I'm not a React-expert, so I may be wrong.

Comment: Aside: in non-native React, elements have `onClick`, not `onPress`...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useReducer` for resetting state in response to click.

It can look like the following

```
function init(initialText) {
  return {text: initialText};
}

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'reset':
      return init(action.payload);
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}

function App({initialText}) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialText, init);
  return (
    <>
      Text: {state.text}
      <button
        onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'reset', payload: initialText})}>
        Reset
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Check the official docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initialization